# jenkins EnvInject plugin does not install

Tags: plugins, jenkins

I have jenkins 1.532.1.
When I want to install the EnvInject Plugin, it shows a warning:

> This plugin makes it possible to have an isolated environment for your
>   jobs. Warning: This plugin is built for Jenkins 1.445 or newer. It may
>   or may not work in your Jenkins.

I go ahead and install it. It says successful but then I can see that it is not installed.
I've already tried restarting jenkins.
Does anyone know whether this plugin was discontinued or whether I will have to downgrade jenkins or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
Downloaded the latest jenkins.war and replaced the current one with it.
On ubuntu, here are the steps:

```
sudo /usr/local/etc/rc.d/jenkins stop
cp jenkins.war /usr/share/jenkins/
sudo /usr/local/etc/rc.d/jenkins start
```